# Unable to redirect a request in IIS using the regex

Tags: iis-8

I am trying to redirect a particular request for various user-agents matching a regex pattern

```
post/([_0-9a-z-]+)
```

When I request

> www.example.com/post/1

the redirect don't occur.But If I set the regex pattern to

```
.*
```

Then the redirect occurs for the request

> www.example.com

I dont know what is wrong here.

Is anything wrong with my pattern?

Answer (score 0):

`post\/([_0-9a-z-]+)`

Added a slash after post. I use https://regex101.com/ to help me debug any Regex stuff I have trouble with. You'll see what you need after putting your text in there :)

Comment: Thats fine !! But its not working too.Even when I am testing the regex in IIS its telling me that regex matches but its not working